# How to stitch multiple images using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, sift, panoramas

I want to create a panorama using multiple images. So basically, the camera will be linearly translated in a plane and around 20-30 images will be taken continuously. I have to create a panorama of those images. I have tried using stitch function and also the traditional way of finding features and matching them and then warping. But I'm not sure if I am doing it properly. How do I proceed?

```
import imutils
import cv2
import glob

input_path = "/Users/akshayacharya/Desktop/Panorama/Raw 
Data/riverside/*.jpg"

# input and sort the images
list_images = glob.glob(input_path)
list_sorted = sorted(list_images)
print(list_sorted)

# output path definition
output_path = "/Users/akshayacharya/Desktop/Panorama/Final 
Panorama/finalpanoex1.jpg"

# initialize empty list and fill all images
images = []
for image in list_sorted:
    image1 = cv2.imread(image)
    image1 = cv2.resize(image1, (720, 480))
    images.append(image1)

print("Read the images")
# this is the final list to stitch
final = [images[0]]
flag = True
print(len(images))
temp = [images[0]]
print(type(temp))

stitcher = cv2.createStitcher() if imutils.is_cv3() else 
cv2.Stitcher_create()

i = 0
while(i < len(images)-1):
    (status, stitched) = stitcher.stitch([temp[0], images[i+1]])
    if status == 0:
        final.append(images[i+1])
        print(f"Succesfully stitch {i} to {i+1}")
        i = i+1

        temp[0] = stitched

        continue
    if status != 0:
        print(f"Succesfully could not stitch {i} to {i + 1}")
        for j in range(i+2, len(images)):
            print(f"now trying {i} to {j}")
            (status, stitchedd) = stitcher.stitch([temp[0], images[j]])
            if status == 0:
                print(f"Succesfully managed to stitch {i} to {j}")
                final.append(images[j])
                i=j
                temp[0] = stitchedd
                break
            if status != 0:
                print(f"Oops could not stitch {i} to {j}")
                print(f"Will now see compatibility between {i} and {j+1}")

            continue

        i += 1
    continue

cv2.imwrite(output_path, temp[0])
```

[I have attached the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX2uC.jpg)```

Comment: 'But I'm not sure if I am doing it properly'. Neither are we. What's your code, what are your results, what's wrong with them?

Comment: @couka I have attached the code and output. Kindly go through it

Answer (score 1):

Panorama image construction pipeline can be keypoint detection and local invariant descriptors; keypoint matching; RANSAC; and perspective warping.

Use the RANSAC algorithm to estimate a homography matrix using matched feature vectors. Apply a warping transformation using the homography matrix obtained from RANSAC. RANSAC improves the matching process detection.
A recent tutorial is available on [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oFRmdDum5k).

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my SIFT notebook for code about features and panorama stitching using opencv [here](https://www.aiismath.com/pages/c_08_features/sift_nb/).